# Facebook realtime.. How are different objects batched together

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

Facebook realtime docs specify that the callback data is of the following format

```
{
  "object": "user",
  "entry": [
    {
      "uid": 1335845740,
      "changed_fields": [
      "name",
      "picture"
      ],
     "time": 232323
    }, {
      "uid": 1234,
      "changed_fields": [
      "friends"
      ],
      "time": 232325
}]}
```

If two different objects, say 'user' and 'page' are to be sent back, does facebook

- Batch them together?
- Send them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different objects are sent in different requests. But if there are many user requests then it will batch those user requests and send it. And also you can have different end points for user and page. The format of page request is also different.
It looks something like this

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "408518775908252",
            "time": 1360643280,
            "changes": [
                {
                    "field": "feed",
                    "value": {
                        "item": "like",
                        "verb": "add",
                        "user_id": 5900878
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```